# Not able to parse the 'data' for login

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i'm trying to login to my college website using python,  i want the source code of the welcome page i.e my dashboard but when i run this i'm getting the same source code as of the login page..is this because im not able to post my info on the login form?   here is the code..

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
 from lxml import html
 import collections

 url = 'http://erp.college_name.edu/'

 opening = requests.get(url)
 r = requests.session()
 stuff= collections.OrderedDict()

 stuff = {

'tbUserName': 'my_username',
'tbPassword': 'my_password',


   }

opens = r.post(url=url, data=stuff)  
soup = BeautifulSoup(opens.text, 'lxml')  
print(soup)
```

any help?

Comment: Where do you get the error? Check out the login form on the page. Normally you have to send back a hidden input field, which prevents CSRF attacks.

Comment: @fodma1  i'm not getting errors but getting the sourcec ode of the login-page instead of my dashboard, yea ,(which means , either the form is not getting the info im parsing or the CSRF issue) the tokens i did them but didn't get the result , (see the update in the question)

Comment: Where did you find the fields to send in POST request? Assuming you found them through your browser console, I'd search around for some other headers that your browser sends and try including those with your request. It could be something silly like the server checking for a reasonable user agent.

Comment: @supersam654 i found all the info under the form-class ,what are the  additional information i need to pass?

Comment: @supersam654 ok ,so i ran this on my terminal and got this ,,  
`Traceback (most recent call last):   

    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\HUNTER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-   32\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
         return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
       UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xa9' in position 5760: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: @supersam654 thanks mate! ,actually there were two hidden tokens,and i was supposed to take the exact value of the tokens from the source code and not to do this `tree = html.fromstring(opening.text)
 token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='name_of_token']/@value")   
[0])) ` , so ,thats it thanks again! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**
so,after getting the tokens
     import collections

```
 url = 'http://erp.name_of_college.edu/'

 opening = requests.get(url)
 tree = html.fromstring(opening.text)
 token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='name_of_token']/@value")   
[0])) 

 r = requests.session()
 data = collections.OrderedDict()
 datas = {

   'tbUserName': 'my_username',
   'tbPassword': 'my_password',
   'name_of_token' : token,


 }

 opens = r.post(url=url, data=datas)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(opens.text, 'lxml')
 print(soup)
```

problem is solved , you need to include the tokens in the parsing data , which are generally as named hidden in the class, and if the problem presists then include more data from the form ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not logging in correctly. Ideally, the site will give you a non-200 status code which you can check with `opens.status_code`. A successful request should start with a 2 (such as `200`). Note that some sites won't provide reasonable status codes even if your request isn't correct.

Comment: i'm getting 200 as the response of `print(opens.status_code)`

Comment: I would save the output as an HTML page and open it in your browser. See if there is an error on the page or something indicating what went wrong.

Comment: actually , the url was `'https://erp.name_of_college.edu/'` but i did `http://` instead of `https://` because it was giving me  `requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')",)` when i only tried to fetch the source-code of the login page, but it wasn't the same in the case of `http://.` could that be a reason?